# Is it possible to combine classification and clustering?

Tags: classification, clustering, data-mining

I am working on a research to detect ssh bruteforce attack using data mining. I would like to using ip geolocation as one of attributes. But, ip geolocation can't be used in classification algorithm due to difference of geolocation of each site (which means that I have to use clustering, right?). So, is there any technique that I can use classification with other attributes first, then use clustering later while using the classification in the system already.

Comment: **what** differences in geolocation? We don't know your data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Let's say that my training data is collected from country A. Most of the legitimate user will come from the country. But if I use this model in another country. It will fail. Since the legitimate user doesn't come from country A anymore.

Comment: Why don't you then train one model per country?

Answer (score 2):

Clustering isn't your general solution when you can't classify.

Never use clustering in an automated approach (except if you are doing vector quantization).

It is an **explorative** method. Meaning tht it **can and will fail** to produce the desired results.

The purpose is to help you understand your data.

It's not a drop in fix for classification issues.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could bin your latitudes and longitudes into larger geographic areas?